# How to convert Excel AM hour/minute mair into seconds as if it were min/sedc pair?

Tags: excel, time

So I was given an excel file with
[image]
 yet the author meant it was a min/sec pair instead of an hour/min pair 1:15:00 AM... 5:16:00 AM. So I wonder - how to turn this wrongly created hour/min excel data into min/sec and then count the total second's amount?

I tried `=A7*1500-4` it is close at this time range yet not at all precise... So how to seamlessly convert hour/min pair into min/sec pair in excel keeping values?

[example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FZQHWGH5kMMIsw8q2xlqmXL1EZg3IIS5zFvHt9Zzw7g/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Divide by 60; format as `mm:ss`

Comment: his suggestion seems not to work for me..( I hope for some formula as answer something like  `=A5/60...`

Comment: example where /60 [does not work](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FZQHWGH5kMMIsw8q2xlqmXL1EZg3IIS5zFvHt9Zzw7g/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: yet how to get an absolute seconds number...?

Comment: can you update the google-sheet with what is the output you're expecting? Manually add the expected data in a new column

Comment: @Gangula: Added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked at your expected output.

[image]

Formula in column B is: `=A1*60*24`

**Make sure format cell is standard!** to see the decimal version of it.

Answer (score -1):

Ron has answered the first part of your question - showing desired value in minute/second format.

(This could also be displayed using a formula `=text(A7/60,"mm:ss")`, which shows the data as desired, but it is just text - not a time value.)

The second part (count the total seconds) can be done using the formula `=value(A7*1440)` .

Comment: Both parts seem not to work [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FZQHWGH5kMMIsw8q2xlqmXL1EZg3IIS5zFvHt9Zzw7g/edit#gid=0)

Comment: For the first part, it worked ok for me in excel, but doesn't work in google sheets.
For the second part, in your example you use /1440 instead of *1440.